# SonarQube Java path traversal attack

Tags: java, security, sonarqube

I have some method for file deleting. I use SonarQube for static analysis of my code.

The method code:

```
private static void removeFile(MyClass someValue) {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(someValue.getRootFolderPath(), someValue.getRelativePath());

    if (!Files.exists(filePath)) {
        LOG.warn("File does not exist", filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        return;
    }

    try {
        Files.delete(filePath.getFileName());
        LOG.debug("File " + someValue.getRelativePath() + " was deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String excMessage = "some info";
        LOG.warn(excMessage, e);
    }
}
```

Sonar says:

> java/nio/file/Paths.get(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;
>   reads a file whose location might be specified by user input

I added call of *normalize* method to prevent path traversal attack.

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(someValue.getRootFolderPath(), someValue.getRelativePath()).normalize();
```

But Sonar still says me about potential path traversal vulnerabilities.

Am I doing something wrong or there is a better solution for preventing such type of attacks which will suits Sonar ?

**UPD**:
Have tried a lot of ways of solving this problem and all of them are wrong by static analysis.

Vulnerable Code:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(FilenameUtils.getName(someValue.getFileName()));
Path filePath = Paths.get("some/path", FilenameUtils.getName(someValue.getFileName()));
Path filePath = Paths.get("some/path", FilenameUtils.getName(fileName));
Path filePath = Paths.get(FilenameUtils.getName(fileName));
File file = new File(someValue.getRootFolderPath(), someValue.getRelativePath());
File file = new File(someValue.getRootFolderPath(), FilenameUtils.getName(someValue.getFileName()));
File file = new File(FilenameUtils.getPath(someValue.getRootFolderPath()), FilenameUtils.getName(someValue.getFileName()));
File file = new File("some/path", FilenameUtils.getName(fileName));
File file = new File(FilenameUtils.getName(fileName));
File file = new File(FilenameUtils.getName("bla-bla-bla"));
```

Comment: Could you share the rule key of the rule which is raising the issue ? I suspect this is a findsecbug rule and not a SonarJava rule.

Comment: Im not sure how to get rule key. There are cwe, owasp-4, wasc in Rule tags.

Comment: http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#PATH_TRAVERSAL_OUT

Comment: try Paths.get(SOME_CONSTANT_OF_ROOT, someValue.getRelativePath()).normalize(); Now you don't fully relay on suplied value.

Comment: You can't tell from the code above whether your application is vulnerable to path traversal or not. It depends on where `someValue` comes from (in *any* execution path). However, this method could be more secure by sanitizing its inputs, thus implementing defense in depth. Things like adding a constant part to the beginning of the constructed path and normalizing appended parts might help, but note that it may not be the full solution in some cases. Unfortunately this can't be answered in short.

Comment: @GaborLengyel, I don't think one should sanitize input. Its actually insecure. Rather we need to validate against known good inputs.

Comment: @Karthik you are of course right in general, and my comment is not very well written, that's why I said there is no short answer, and also that it would be *more* secure. In this type of vulnerability, input sanitization, together with other measures of course (see the reference to defense in depth above) can be effective, but explaining it all would be much longer than a comment. Whitelisting is of course the best option, but most of the times not possible. No offense, I should have crafted my comment better.

Answer (score 1):

Before fixing anything, please understand the vulnerabilities. What this means is that when sonar (or any other similar tool) highlights a piece of code, don't try to get rid of the issue as quick as possible. Understand what the issue is. Do some research on the highlighted vulnerability.

This piece of code exposes for an attacker to get an understanding of the directory structure or get access to files which shouldn't be. normalize() is one of the step to fix this vulnerability, not the full fix. On how to approach a fix please read [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System#Path_traversal)

A sample fix too is given [here](http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#SCALA_PATH_TRAVERSAL_IN). I hope that helps.

Comment: I've got the main idea of the attack and I'm not interested in just getting rid of the issue. I had already visited owasp before asking this question and from there I've got idea about normalization. I think that normalize fixes my problem cause of app specs: user shouldn't get info about parent folder. But Sonar still raises Vulnerability even with using FilenameUtils in the Paths.get. I suppose that rule cannot correctly analize Java 7 Files and Path/Paths. Maybe I'm wrong. And I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you also try not having the rootFolderPath in MyClass& derive directly from somewhere else; also having just "someValue.getRelativePath()" as a method param? I think it is flagging right as the file is accessed completely by the method parameter. There is this pattern in the sample solution link that I have already shared. If you check the vulnerability description, it says:

"A file is opened to read its content. The filename comes from an input parameter. If an unfiltered parameter is passed to this file API, files from an arbitrary filesystem location could be read."

Comment: I've tried a lot of ways (in UPD). Including your and Sonar advises. But still get this warn about path traversal vulnerability.
I suppose that the solution which suits me is to use normalize. Cause rootFolderPath is some kind of admin settings in app, I hope admins are not going to attack what they administrate. The only value which I get from user is RelativePath. MyClass just stores this values (also some getters/setters).
I guess that it's more important to realize what this vulnerability is, how it can damage your system/app and how to protect your system/app from it.